# using Relationships field, want to display job listings per facility

Tags: relationships

I have a "Job Openings" channel with a relationship field. The field relates to the "Facility" channel. So when a user creates a new job opening entry, they relate the opening to the facility. Now in my template I want to display a list of facilities ONLY IF THEY HAVE JOB OPENINGS, then below the name of the facility, display all job openings.

I started with a channel entries tag for the facilities. How do I setup the conditional so it detects if there is a parent(job opening), display the facility title, then display all job openings for that facility? I only want the facility name to appear once, with all job openings for that facility below it.

The code I have below is not correct and displays the facility title for every job opening. I'm not sure how to setup the conditional correctly. Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="facilities" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}

            {parents field="job_facility"}
               {if parents:count >= "1"}
               <article class="job_summary">
                   <h1>{title}</h1>
                       <h2>Job Opening</h2>
                       <a href=""><h3>{parents:title}</h3></a>
               </article>
               {/if}
            {/parents}

            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

***This is what I want...***

- Facility 1

  - job opening
- Facility 2

  - job opening
  - job opening
- Facility 8

  - job opening

***And this is what I'm getting...***

- Facility 1

  - job opening
- Facility 2

  - job opening
- Facility 2

  - job opening
- Facility 8

  - job opening

Comment: Try this: Around your h1 tags add {if parents:count =="1"}<h1>{title}</h1>{/if}

Comment: Sean, thanks for taking a look, Unfortunately that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding a bit on @CreateSean's comment to your question, you can use the `parents:count` and `parents:total_results` variables much like you'd use them in the Channel entries tag to generate "wrapper" markup.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="facilities" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}

  {parents}
      {if parents:count == "1"}
        <article class="job_summary">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <h2>Job Opening</h2>
      {/if}

             <a href=""><h3>{parents:title}</h3></a>

      {if parents:count == parents:total_results}
        </article>
      {/if}
  {/parents}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: So simple, embarrassed my thought process didn't go there. Thanks Derek!

Comment: one more quick question, is it possible to pull grid column data? For example, in the parent entry I have a Grid field called "facility_contact_info"  with a field name called "joblink". Can the contents of "joblink" be pulled in as well?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out.